# Why did the cli.bat tool of Apache IoTDB cannot be started after setting `rpc_thrift_compression_enable = true`?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask about `cli.bat` cannot be started after `rpc_thrift_compression_enable` being set to `true` in `iotdb-engine.properties` of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.4. What may be the reason for this situation? I tried to use a different computer to access IoTDB, and the system prompted `can not establish connection with jdbc:iotdb://172.16.3.116:6667/: Socket is closed by peer.`

Answer (score 0):

If the Apache IoTDB server has already set `rpc_thrift_compression_enable=true`, then when using command, the `Cli` tool must add `-c`. See if adding this will solve your problem.